# VBA Script to duplicate a value, replace forward slashes and merge whilst adding a certain value on the end in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel sheet containing values looking like this:

```
BL/ER/D11/fmp000005578/0001
BL/ER/D11/fmp000005578/0002
BL/ER/D11/fmp000005578/0002
```

I need them to look like this:

```
/data01/BL/ER/D11/fmp000005578/BL_ER_D11_fmp000005578_0001_1.jpg
/data01/BL/ER/D11/fmp000005578/BL_ER_D11_fmp000005578_0002_1.jpg
/data01/BL/ER/D11/fmp000005578/BL_ER_D11_fmp000005578_0003_1.jpg
```

The pattern pretty much is:

1. Remove the numbers from the end. (`BL/ER/D11/fmp000005578/`)
2. Duplicate the value, replacing the forward slashes with underscores for that specific value. (`BL/ER/D11/fmp000005578/BL_ER_D11_fmp000005578_`)
3. Add the numbers back. (`BL/ER/D11/fmp000005578/BL_ER_D11_fmp000005578_0001`)
4. Add `_1.jpg` to the end. (`BL/ER/D11/fmp000005578/BL_ER_D11_fmp000005578_0001_1.jpg`)
5. Add `/data01/` to the front. (`/data01/BL/ER/D11/fmp000005578/BL_ER_D11_fmp000005578_0001_1.jpg`)

This process needs to be repeated for every value in the same column.

There are multiple worksheets/tabs in one spreadsheet, so somehow the macro should be able do it across multiple worksheet/tabs if it's possible.

The code I currently have is:

```
Sub FileDirectoryRegExTest()
    Dim regEx As New RegExp
    Dim strPattern As String
    Dim strInput As String
    Dim strReplace As String
    Dim Myrange As Range

    Set Myrange = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A4620")

    For Each c In Myrange
        strPattern = "([A-Z]{2}\/[A-Z]{2}\/[A-Z][0-9]{2}\/[a-z]{3}[0-9]{9}\/)([0-9]{4})"

        If strPattern <> "" Then
            strInput = c.Value
            strReplace = "$1"

            With regEx
                .Global = True
                .MultiLine = True
                .IgnoreCase = False
                .Pattern = strPattern
            End With

            If regEx.test(strInput) Then
                c.Offset(0, 1) = regEx.Replace(strInput, "$2")
            Else
                c.Offset(0, 1) = ""
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I've used this code for a previous function, but I'm not too sure if I can re-purpose this code to perform these specific functions.

If you could edit this script or create a new one that performs this function, that would be brilliant, thanks!

Thank you!

Aydan H.

Comment: Do your values `BL/ER/D11/fmp000005578/0001` have constant length?

Comment: @avb There's 62000+ values, but from what I have seen of them so far, yes. They stay in that same general format, as I have highlighted using the RegEx in the scrip above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub FileDirectoryRegExTest()
For Each sht In Sheets
    lastRow = sht.Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row
    Set Myrange = sht.Range("A2:A" & lastRow)
    For Each c In Myrange
        c.Offset(0, 1) = "/data01/" & Left(c, Len(c) - 4) & Replace(Left(c, Len(c) - 4), "/", "_") & Right(c, 4) & "_1.jpg"
    Next c
Next sht
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it for multiple tabs within a worksheet? Image: https://snag.gy/cIhQ5N.jpg

Comment: The code runs for each tab. You may, however, have an issue if the ranges are different on each tab. You should find the last used row using lastRow = sht.Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row and set the range like this: Set Myrange = sht.Range("A2:A & lastRow)

Comment: Can you update your code above with that edit, I don't fully understand. Thank you! Kinda new to all this VBA script

Answer (score 1):

This can be done without regex, which I like a lot, but they are slow, see this code:

```
Function something(inString As String) As String
Dim lastSlash As Integer
Dim firstPart As String, lastPart As String
    lastSlash = Len(inString) - InStr(1, StrReverse(inString), "/")
    firstPart = Mid(inString, 1, lastSlash)
    lastPart = Mid(inString, lastSlash + 2, 9999)
    something = firstPart & "/" & Replace(firstPart, "/", "_") & "_" & lastPart & "_1.jpg"
End Function
```

You can even use it as a formula on your sheet.

Comment: How would I put that into a module, do I need to add Sub x() and end sub, at the top and bottom?

Comment: Nope, besides subs there are functions, just put it in a module and you can use it as a formula on sheet (=somethig(A1)) or if you need to use it in your VBA code use it as `.Range("A1").Value = somethig(.Range("B1").Value)`

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to use regular expression for this?

How about a simple bit of code:

```
"/data01/" & Mid(c.Value, 1, Len(c.Value) - 4) & Replace(c.Value, "/", "_") & "_1.jpg"
```

Not sure if the last bit of numbers before `_1` are meant to be incremented?. If they do you could just add a counter in the string